# if statement when so much is loaded, it begins a new row

Tags: javascript, html, json, if-statement, bootstrap-modal

So I need to make an if statement that, whenever id 0 to 3 (4 images) are loaded, make a new row of 0 to 3 images, this same do i need to do with words (probably works the same)

I'm quite new with if statements etc. I just don't know where to start with this..
The images and words load from a JSON file, and I already have the first bit of codes.

Like the `var html = '<div class="row">';` to the `html += '</div>';`
I need an if statement to let the images load in a row of 4 images/words nexto eachother.
And then make a new row, automaticly.

I guess it sounds complicated.. I hope someone can help me.

JSON,

```
{"main_object": {
    "imagesJ": ["beak", "cat", "egg", "meel", "milk", "passport", "spoon", "thee"],
    "wordsJ": ["næb", "kat", "æg", "mel", "mælk", "pas", "ske", "te"]
}
}
```

```js
var jsonData = "noJson";
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

$(document).ready(function(){
var jsonData = 'empty';
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "./js/data.json",
    dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response){
        jsonData = JSON.parse(response);

        console.log('ok');
          var imagesJ = jsonData.main_object.imagesJ;
          var wordsJ = jsonData.main_object.wordsJ;
          var html = '<div class="row">';
          var html2 = '';

          for(i = 0; i < imagesJ.length; i++) {
//html += '</div><div class="row">';
//if statement that whenthere are 0-3 = 4 pictures it begins a new block of code wich makes 0-3 = 4 pictures, that are in bootstrap row PROBEER DIT ALLEEN MET STACKOVERFLOW OF ANDERE INTERNET DINGEN
            html += '<div class="col-md-2"><img src="/sleepopdracht/img/'+imagesJ[i]+'.jpg" alt="images" id="'+[i]+'"></div>';
          }
          html += '</div>';

          document.getElementById('images').innerHTML = html;

          for (i = 0; i < wordsJ.length; i++) {
            html2 += '<p>'+wordsJ[i]+'</p>';
          }
          document.getElementById('words').innerHTML = html2;

      },
      error: function(){
        console.log('JSON could not be loaded.');
      }
    });

        console.log(jsonData);

});
```

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 20%;
  /*border-bottom: thick solid grey;*/
}

body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
}
.images img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#img4, #img5, #img6, #img7 {
  top: 5%;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 5%;
  /*border-top: thick solid grey;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sleepopdracht</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>

  </header>

    <div class="container" id="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <img src="/sleepopdracht/img/'+imagesJ[i]+'.jpg" alt="images" id="'+[i]+'">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          a
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          a
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          a
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          a
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          a
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          a
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          a
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="images" id="images"></div>
                                          <div class="words" id="words"></div>
    </div>


  <footer>
  </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in HTML I have made those rows, they need to become one and loop themselfes a little like `<div class="col-md-2">
          <img src="/sleepopdracht/img/'+imagesJ[i]+'.jpg" alt="images" id="'+[i]+'">
        </div>`

[This is my result right now.](http://prntscr.com/alx1pk)

[And this is what it needs to resemble closely.](http://prntscr.com/alx28s)

Comment: you want your for loop to skip every 3 items, so you can do `for (var i = 0; i < imagesJ.length; i+3)` and then you can do `var image1 = imagesJ[i]; var image2 = imagesJ[i + 1]; image3 = imagesJ[i + 2];`

Comment: You could use the Modulo operator:
`if((i%4)==3) html += '</div><div class="row">';`

Comment: By the way, your code is vulnerable to HTML injection. You should either escape the variables, build the DOM manually using document.createElement, document.createTextNode and Node.appendChild, or use a Templating engine. (Here is mine: https://mvsync.ch/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
for(i = 0; i < imagesJ.length; i++){      
  html += '<div class="col-md-2"><img src="/sleepopdracht/img/' + imagesJ[i] + '.jpg" alt="images" id="' + [i] + '"></div>';
  if((i + 1) % 4 == 0){
    html += '</div><div class="row">';
  }
}
```

Comment: could you maybe explain a little how I can make such codes myself.. I can't seem to find the right words or combinations to make loops like that yet..